# Can I increase HTML5 canvas resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

Html canvas decreases the resolution of images and shapes. Is there a way by which we can increase the quality?

Comment: Create a bigger canvas.

Comment: just create a bigger canvas. For example:
canvasElement.width = 1920;
canvasElement.height = 1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
const width = ..., height = ..., scale = 2;
const canvas = document.querySelector('...')
canvas.style.width = width;
canvas.style.height = height;
canvas.width = width * scale;
canvas.height = height * scale;
```